# e-commerce vs ecommerce

Tags: spelling

When using words like: *ecommerce, ebanking*, etc. What is the right way to write them? With dash like: *e-commerce, e-banking*? or as a one word: ecommerce, ebanking, etc.?

I do not want to use the long term: electronic commerce, electronic banking.

Comment: Ngrams make it clear: [e-banking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=e-banking%2Cebanking&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ce%20-%20banking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cebanking%3B%2Cc0), [e-commerce](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=e-commerce%2Cecommerce&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ce%20-%20commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cecommerce%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of the hyphen (or lack thereof) in e-mail, e-commerce, etc, is not decided. If you are writing in a situation where you must abide by a style guide, then follow its requirements. Otherwise, pick one of the spelling styles and use it consistently. In Britain, where I live, 'e-mail' was common, but is now seen by many people as old-fashioned, as are many hyphenated forms, and 'email' is replacing it.

[E-mail versus email](https://grammarist.com/style/e-mail-email/)

Answer (score 1):

Using your title as a Google query, there are many articles discussing this question, and with varying conclusions. The short answer is that the word is too new to be right or wrong yet. Consider your tone and audience and let that guide your decision. The hyphenated form seems more common in formal use and the conjoined form seems more common in its industry.

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that Tmall global is a good choice for cross-border e-commerce, because it can face the large market of China, and many Chinese people have a special preference for imported goods. Even if you don't believe what I said, you can also judge whether it will be successful or not after entering the Chinese market according to the sales volume of businesses stationed in Tmall global during the double 11 Festival last year There is enough room for development. [There](http://www.cdshuji.com) is also a lot of knowledge about Tmall global here. Those who are interested can learn about it.